# How to get Selected TreeViewItems in TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am Populating a treeView with the help of a recursive function as shown in the code. For each treeviewItem, i am adding checkboxes using stackpanel. The treeView gets populated Properly as shown in the image below. The Problem i am having right now is getting the selected nodes/checkboxes (more specifically, i need all the selected "TreeviewItem" objects). I am using treeview control for the first time and i googled around a while for the solution...but with no success.

Note: The TreeView will have around 6000 Nodes. So, a solution other than traversing  through all the checkboxes is needed.

[image]

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   TreeViewItem ParentNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = stackedLook("Sub N Node 0"), IsExpanded = true };
   CreatePSTree(RootNode, ParentNode);
   treeView1.items.Add(ParentNode);
 }

 private void CreatePSTree(Product RootNode,  TreeViewItem ParentNode)
 {
      for (int i = 1; i <= RootNode.Products.Count; i++)
       {
        Product NewNode = RootNode.Products.Item(i);
        TreeViewItem NewTreeItem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = stackedLook(NewNode.get_Name()), IsExpanded = false };
        ParentNode.Items.Add(NewTreeItem);                    

        //Recursive calls for each product Node  
        CreatePSTree(NewNode, NewTreeItem);                
      }
  }

 private object stackedLook(string displayText)
   {
     // create stack panel
     StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
     stack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

     //Add Checkbox for Node selection
      CheckBox checkBoxForNode = new CheckBox();
      checkBoxForNode.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(4);

      // Label displaying the Node name
      Label lbl = new Label();
      lbl.Content = displayText;
      lbl.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(-2);

      // Add into stack
      stack.Children.Add(checkBoxForNode);
      stack.Children.Add(lbl);

      return stack;
  }
```

Comment: You would have to traverse all listviewitems and check its template for a checkbox, and then determine whether the checkbox is selected

Comment: The treeview will have around 6000-7000 nodes. So, it will take a hell lot of time for each selection Changed

Comment: Oh damn. Well maybe you can set up an IsChecked event handler for each checkbox within the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding eventhandlers at all places where i add new node in treeview along with using an observable collection to keep track of selections and changes

```
ParentNode.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(SelectedNodeItem);

void SelectedNodeItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    TreeViewItem SelectedTreeViewItem = ((TreeViewItem)e.Source);
 }
```